# What would be Gilbert Ryle's necessary and sufficient conditions for being a human being?

Tags: metaphysics, identity, self

One of my students asked me this question and I can't answer it. I thought it was a great question. Any suggestions on an equally good answer?

(I'm not a trained philosopher, I'm a historian. I teach Grade 12 philosophy because I was the one available to pick up the course, and I think it's a crucial course that all young people should take).

Comment: See [Gilbert Ryle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ryle/), particularly Behaviourism and Self-knowledge. Maybe relevant *The Concept of Mind* (1949), page 177: "To conclude, there is nothing mysterious or occult about the range of
higher order acts and attitudes, which are apt to be inadequately covered
by the umbrella-title ‘self-consciousness’. They are the same in kind as
the higher order acts and attitudes exhibited in the dealings of people
with one other. Indeed the former are only a special application of the
latter and are learned first from them."

Comment: Thus, we may say that "human nature" is the disposition to perform high-order acts .

Comment: Isn't that a circular argument, if higher-order acts are acts that human beings do?

Comment: A reverse homework question! Are those allowed on the site? :-)

Comment: I'm the instructor asking on behalf of a student because I can't answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that your question is more complicated than it looks. It is best to distinguish between being a human being and being a person. we can then treat "human being" as a biological classification like "dog" or "cat" or "brontosaurus", and "person" as a being that is conscious and can act (in the sense that only people can). That's very rough and ready, but it is a starting-point.

Given that distinction, I think that you are asking about the necessary and sufficient conditions for being a person. There's no straightforward answer to that. But it is clear that human beings are a paradigm of a person.

To understand this, think of the way that we define a colour by ostensive definition - by pointing to a sample and classify other colours by comparing them to the sample. The standard examples of our weights and measures are another case like this. It's not really a matter of necessary and sufficient conditions.

Concepts of this kind are essential if we are ever to break out of the endless circle of words defined by other words.

The best way to approach this question is to get your students to think about cases where we have a problem.

Animals are an excellent starting-point. Consider why we treat animals like dogs and cats as conscious, partly rational beings, but not persons in the way that human beings are (most of them, for most of the time.) Are insects (and perhaps most) fish persons? In what ways are they like persons and in what ways are they unlike persons?

Machines, especially robots and the debate about AI are other good cases. You might like to them to think about zombies as portrayed in some movies and how they are very like human persons, but also terrifyingly unlike them. The story of Frankenstein is another good case.

I think you will find that the most useful approach is to resist pushing the discussion to a yes/no binary answer and to focus on identifying the relevant similarities and differences between examples. You might also like to bring in the moral status of persons as an essential part of the concept; this is often explained by saying that it is wrong to treat a person as simply a means to an end - to "use" them.

The crucial thing about persons is that we treat them in a way different from non-persons - we interact with them and they interact with us in special ways. That is the critical thing and we learn it by interacting with people from the moment we are born.

Encyclopedias often are a good way of getting a general understanding. Try [Wikipedia - Person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person). You might also find [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy - Persons as Means](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/persons-means/) useful.

For more about definition in general, see [Wikipedia - Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definition) especially the last section on limitations of definition, and for ostensive definition in particular, see [Wikipedia - Ostensive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostensive_definition).

ADDED LATER

My approach to this answer starts from the fact that it is not possible to give a short answer to the question and difficult to give a long one. Ryle is often classed as an analytic philosopher, but he was unlike most other analytic philosophers in that he did not pursue the standard idea of logical analysis, with its attendant insistence on formal definitions with necessary and sufficient conditions.

His analyses were conducted in ordinary language, which he takes as the bedrock of our understanding of the world. His discussion of the mind was dominated by his rejection of the Cartesian Dualist account of the mind. It is aimed at showing that the problems it tries to resolve are not really problems and that it creates new problems and absurdities as it is developed.

He does not even attempt to develop a formal definition, but takes the fact that you are reading his text as showing that you understand what a person is. In many ways his writing about these topics is similar to Wittgenstein's and in some way is just as elusive.

Roughly, he insists that we identify persons/human beings by what they do, and what they can do, with an emphasis on distinctive activities like speaking and thinking. He emphasizes our dispositions to behave - what we do, what we can do and what we tend to do. So he is often classified as a behaviourist, but this is misleading. Nonetheless, it would not be wrong to say that we identify people as people because of what they do or how they behave.

I can illustrate his approach by asking you to think about how you recognize as a person the human being walking towards you as you walk down a street. It is not just the physical movements, but the exchange of glances and lookings away, with maybe a smile or a nod or a fixed look ahead. That tells you what you can expect and how you should behave as you pass each other. It's a subtle exchange and a (brief) relationship.

For a more thorough and articulate discussion see [Wikipedia - Gilbert Ryle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ryle/).

Comment: This answer is good as to what a human is, but not so much as to what Ryle thought.  The answer references consciousness as central to personhood, but Ryle's whole point in "The concept of Mind" is that the "in there" aspect of what we imagine as consciousness, is a "category error".  He defines consciousness solely in behavioral disposition terms, where consciousness is just a shorthand for the behavioral analysis.  The denial of Theory of Mind, and near uselessness of the behaviorist approach to studying psychology and consciousness led to the abandonment of Ryle's approach and ideas.

Comment: The critical phase of Ryle’s argument is against dualism. It seems to me correct and I notice that you do not challenge it. His framing of the alternative fails to distinguish between behaviour as physical event and behaviour as action by a person and so does not recognize that behaviour is interpreted very differently in these contexts. Wittgenstein's discussion of these issues is, admittedly, better.